# how to config WinEdt to show both TeXify and PDFTeXify buttons on toolbar?

Tags: winedt

I know this is a question from a lazy guy. Now both TeXifyy and PDFTeXify buttons belong to the same dropdown button on the toolbar.

Is it possible to configure them both on the toolbar so that each can be reached via 1 mouse click?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is very useful: most of the time, once you've chosen a compiler via the drop-down menu, you won't change it very often, so that you'll launch it with a mouse click. Nevertheless, here's how to do it.

In the Options interface, open Toolbar.ini, and add these lines where you want the icons to appear:

```
BUTTON="|"
BUTTON="PDFLaTeXify"
BUTTON="PDFTeXify"
BUTTON="|"
```

The separator buttons ("|") are not necessary, it's only to group the PDF(La)Texify buttons together. 
Then click on the leftmost icon in the Options interface to validate the modification yoou've just made to Toolbarbar.ini. That's all.

This is what I obtained:

[image]